# 1D topological insulator

Tags: condensed-matter, topological-insulators

This question is inspired by another [one](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/3282/simple-models-that-exhibit-topological-phase-transitions) about the simplest model of topological insulator, where 4tnemele showed a nice two band model in the answer.

I read that and am wondering if we and push that to one dimension.

For example, by analogy to the graphene case, if we have a Hamiltonian in 1D (say x) as $H(k_x)=(k_x-k_0)+m$ for $k_x>0$. When $k_x=k_0$, one has $m>0$. $H(k_x)=(k_x+k_0)+m$ for $k_x<0$. When $k_x=-k_0$, one has $m<0$. A smooth connection in between, we will have a conductive edge (two ends in the 1D structure), right?

If I want to make a intuitive picture like below, is it correct?
[image]

Any suggestion for real materials show this behavior?

Comment: I can't say anything too insightful as an answer to your actual question, but I think it's interesting to note that novel "edge modes" on the free ends of 1D systems are actually quite generic, two beautiful examples being emergent spin-1/2 excitations at the tips of S=1 Heisenberg magnets (see also the AKLT chain) or Majorana fermion modes on the ends of the Kitaev chain.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Topological insulators are gapped states of free fermions with
particle number conservation and time-reversal symmetry. According to the [K-theory](http://arxiv.org/abs/0901.2686) classification, there is no Topological insulator in 1D.

However, 1D interacting fermions with time-reversal symmetry do have non-trivial symmetry protected topological phases if the particle number is conserved only mod n. The result can be obtained from group cohomology theory [arXiv:1106.4772](http://arxiv.org/abs/1106.4772) of Chen, Gu, Liu, and Wen.

Comment: Dear Xiao-Gang Wen, if you cite yourself, it would be good if you could say so explicitly in your answers, not just in the links, cf. [Physics.SE policy](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/582/how-do-you-cite-yourself) and [SE policy](http://physics.stackexchange.com/faq#promotion).

Comment: Hey Prof. Wen, how to understand the particle number conservation in topological insulators. Normally people only say it is time-reversal invariant. Thank you!

Comment: @Qmechanic I thought "Chen, Gu, Liu, and Wen" explicitly contains my name Wen. Jeremy: Yes, normally people only say it is time-reversal invariant. But "insulator" implies  particle number conservation.

Comment: Dear @Xiao-Gang Wen: What is meant is, that it would be best, if you could refer to yourself using a 1st person pronoun.

Comment: @Jeremy (sorry for commenting on such an old question). The reason why people don't mention particle conservation is that they are using the standard complex Hamiltonians of the form $H = \sum_{ij}H_{ij}a^\dagger_ia_j$ which explicitly conserves particle number. Except if the Hamiltonian has particle-hole symmetry, which means it describes a superconductor in the mean-field approximation (using Nambu spinors). (Continued)

Comment: In the Kitaev paper cited above, a general (particle non-conserving) Hamiltonian $\sum_{ij}(H_{ij}a^\dagger_ia_j + G_{ij} a_i a_j+ h.c.)$ is mapped to $H = \frac i4\sum_{IJ}A_{IJ}c_Ic_J$ by using Majorana fermions $c_I^\dagger = c_I$, $\{c_I,c_J\} = 2\delta_{IJ}$. The advantage is that $A_{IJ}$ is a REAL, anti-symmetric matrix and one can more clearly derive the 8-fold Bott periodicity of the classification of topological insulators (see Kitaevs paper above). But now one has to explicitly demand particle number conservation, which is why Prof. Wen mentions it explicitly.